# Firebase Login Authentication

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

Using ,https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/tree/master/codelabs/chat as a reference for login, i seem to face problems when i type

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    setEnabledAuthProvider(AuthProviderType.PASSWORD);
}
```

I only can type AuthProvider and not AuthProviderType why is that so, it hints me to type social provider.

Comment: This is [the setEnabledAuthProvider() method](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/library/src/main/java/com/firebase/ui/auth/core/FirebaseLoginBaseActivity.java#L108) you're calling and this is the [AuthProviderType enum](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/library/src/main/java/com/firebase/ui/auth/core/AuthProviderType.java). The type clearly exists, so you must be doing something else wrong when including it.

Answer (score 0):

You probably ara missing this line:

```
import com.firebase.ui.auth.core.AuthProviderType;
```